# Trying to access text of a novel omitting the chapter titles and epigraphs

Tags: python

I am trying to access the text in a novel. However, I do not want to count chapter titles and indented quotes that are below every chapter title (epigraphs).

Example:

```
• CHAPTER 1 •

    "There are many questions in this universe unanswered"

             -Anonymous
```

(**This is where the actual text in each chapter would be**).....

```
• CHAPTER 2 •

    "Another quote"

             -Random Person
```

(**Text for chapter 2**)

Here I would not want to count the chapter title or the quote below it in my calculations, only the text below this in the chapter. Because every chapter has this is makes it hard for me to do.

I tried using someone else's command-line tool that broke each novel up into chapters (each one its own file), but that program did not work for this example because the chapter title is surrounded by bullet point characters, as well as it might still count the quote beneath the title. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

text = '''


• CHAPTER 1 •

    "There are many questions in this universe unanswered"

             -Anonymous
(This is where the actual text in each chapter would be).....

• CHAPTER 2 •

    "Another quote"

             -Random Person
         
(Text for chapter 2)


'''


print(''.join(re.split('•.*\s+".*\s+-[a-zA-Z ]+\s+',text)))
```